# С/С++, динамическая память malloc и calloc

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Помогите разобраться, как правильно работать с динамической памятью в Си. Как я понял, "malloc" выделяет память под целое число, a "calloc" выделяет память под массив символов. Я написал Класс Строка, и дал ему 2 конструктора, один создает строку а 2-ой просто клонирует его ... Проблема в том, что он неправильно выделяет память, и я получаю мусор в конце, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему это происходит.

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream.h>#include <conio.h>#include <string.h>#include <alloc.h>class Stroka {  private:    char *sir;    int length;  public:     Stroka(const Stroka & str);     Stroka(char *);    ~Stroka() {    getch();    cout << "Vizov destructora dlea -> " << sir << endl;    free(sir);    } void vivod();};// Конструктор копированияStroka::Stroka(const Stroka & t){    length = t.length;    sir = (char *) calloc(length, sizeof(char));    strcpy(sir, t.sir);}Stroka::Stroka(char *s){    length = strlen(s);    sir = (char *) calloc(length, sizeof(char));    strcpy(sir, s);}// Вывод на экранvoid Stroka::vivod(){    cout << " -> '" << sir << "' dlina " << length << " simvolov" << endl;}void main(){    clrscr();    cout << "  Konstruktor " << endl;    Stroka w("This is a test, word1 word2 word3 word4 ABCDEF");    w.vivod();    cout << endl;    getch();    cout << " Copia Konstruktora " << endl;    Stroka clon = w;    clon.vivod();    cout << endl;    getch();    getch();}
```

Вместо строки "This is a test, word1 word2 word3 word4 ABCDEF" я получаю клон(копию) с мусором "This is a test, word1 word2 word3 word4 ABCDEF3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решается просто - дело не в calloc или malloc, а в том, что признак конца строки - символ '\0' (т.е. нулевой байт). Вы выделяете память ровно на длину строки, но не учитываете этот нулевой байт, поэтому он затирается кем-либо.

Проблему решит вот такое выделение calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));

p.s. Поработайте над стилем кодирования - на самом деле ничего страшного в Вашем коде нет, но он выглядит как смесь C и C++.

Comment: calloc выделяет память под массив любых данных, не обязательно символов. Хорошим стилем в С++ является использование оператора new вместо malloc/calloc

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!!!